# How to provide reasonable default bounds for Google Places API's getAutocompletePredictions() method?

Tags: android, google-places-api

I am using this method:

```
Places.GeoDataApi.getAutocompletePredictions(googleApiClient, query, bounds, AutocompleteFilter.create(null))
```

It requires a LatLntBounds object with a northeast and a southwest LatLng points as the bounds of the query, but I dont want to provide any.

Tried with null, but got a null pointer exception
Tried with:

```
LatLng southWest = new LatLng(85, -180);
LatLng northEast = new LatLng(-85, 180);
LatLngBounds bounds = new LatLngBounds(southWest, northEast);
```

but got `IllegalArgumentException: southern latitude exceeds northern latitude (85.0 > -85.0)`

So how do I:

a) get the current user location's reasonable bounds

b) get the world bounds

so that I can kickstart this API

Comment: Why don't you want to provide the bounds?

Comment: because I want to get SOME results first, to see it working, THEN I will think about providing bounds.

Comment: The NullPointerException when passing a null bounds sounds like a bug. Can you report it [here](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/entry?template=Places%20API%20for%20Android%20-%20Bug) so the team can take a look?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It requires the bounds to work. Just create them.

```
import com.google.maps.android.SphericalUtil;

final double HEADING_NORTH_EAST = 45;
final double HEADING_SOUTH_WEST = 215;
final double diagonalBoundsSize = 1000; // 1km

LatLng centre = new LatLng(85, -180);

LatLng northEast = SphericalUtil.computeOffset(centre, diagonalBoundsSize / 2, HEADING_NORTH_EAST);
LatLng southWest = SphericalUtil.computeOffset(centre, diagonalBoundsSize / 2, HEADING_SOUTH_WEST);
LatLngBounds bounds = new LatLngBounds(southWest, northEast);
```

Comment: What area from the world will this cover?

Comment: Where do I get the SphericalUtil class from?

Comment: I have no idea, create `LatLng centre` for whichever point you want. Set `diagonalBoundsSize` for the distance in metres you wish to cover.

Comment: import com.google.maps.android.*; cannot be resolved

Comment: @J.K. add `compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.3.4'` to your gradle dependencies.

Comment: @ColinGillespie - how bout in eclipse?

Comment: doesn't work me:

` LatLng centre = new LatLng(59.939095, 30.315868); //sankt-petersburg
final double diagonalBoundsSize = 20000; // 20km

mBoundsSpherical = new LatLngBounds(
                SphericalUtil.computeOffset(centre, diagonalBoundsSize / 2, 215),
                SphericalUtil.computeOffset(centre, diagonalBoundsSize / 2, 45)
        );

PendingResult<AutocompletePredictionBuffer> results =
                    Places.GeoDataApi.getAutocompletePredictions(mGoogleApiClient, constraint.toString(), mBoundsSpherical, mPlaceFilter); // retrieves locations in Moscow `